# cmake + sdl - disable sdlmain

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl

I"m linking SDL with my application using cmake (winxp sp3, cmake 2.8.4).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(SDL REQUIRED)

set(src WIN32 main.cpp)

include_directories(${QT_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_QTGUI_INCLUDE_DIR} ${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(test ${src})

target_link_libraries(test ${SDL_LIBRARY})
```

Problem: SDL_LIBRARY contains SDLmain.lib, and I need to avoid linking with it (I already have one other library that contains main but isn't mentioned in this cmakelists.txt example).

I need to remove SDLmain entry from SDL_LIBRARY. This must be done without using hard-coded paths to the library - basically I need to keep using find_package to set up sdl-related variables, but I must ensure that SDLmain is not within SDL_LIBRARY. Also, I'm using cmake 2.8.4 which doesn't have string(FIND).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does that help?

`FindSDL.cmake`:

```
# This module responds to the the flag:
# SDL_BUILDING_LIBRARY
# If this is defined, then no SDL_main will be linked in because 
# only applications need main().
# Otherwise, it is assumed you are building an application and this
# module will attempt to locate and set the the proper link flags
# as part of the returned SDL_LIBRARY variable.
```

Comment: Well... I'm not technically building a library, but this works.